# Applying changes to elements in array

Tags: python, list

I'm extremely new to python

I have an array of string that I want to lowercase, how do I apply changes to an array using for x in array? as such:

```
with open(pathBlackList+'/blacklist.txt') as file:
    blackList = [line.strip() for line in file]
for i in blackList:
    i=i.lower()
    print i
return blackList
```

This code I wrote doesnt apply the lower case to the array, I can understand why its doing this, it's just lowercasing the variable i, which isnt a part of the array. So how do I apply the changes to the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply convert the strings to lower case in the comprehension itself, like this

```
blackList = [line.strip().lower() for line in file]
```

Also, you might want to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to compose the path strings like this

```
with open(os.path.join(pathBlackList, 'blacklist.txt')) as file:
    return [line.strip().lower() for line in file]
```